# The word "new" may be an Adverb or an Adjective

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence, ambiguity, literature, shakespeare

I am trying to understand this sentence where the word 'new' can both be an adverb and also an adjective. Can someone please help me explain the ambiguous structure and the meaning conveyed in the below sonnet? Understandably, poets like to introduce ambiguity intentionally to convey simultaneous meanings....

> So shall I live, supposing thou art true,
> Like a deceived husband – so love’s face
> May still seem love to me, though altered **new**:
> Thy looks with me, thy heart in other place.
> (Shakespeare, W. (1977). Sonnet 93)

Comment: Literary criticism is beyond the scope of this forum; but _new_ as an adverb is equivalent to _anew_ or _newly_, as in _new-born baby, new-mown hay_.

Comment: Other than rhyming with *true*, I'd go with *now* over *new*. But anew works. Either way, the poet's got the limited syllables to deal with. And second-guessing Will, I'd add that *new* adds little information.

Comment: But it adds a syllable. This is poetry, which is lovely but beyond grammar and usage -- nobody can use poetry.

Comment: Poetry is good for quoting: The fog comes. on little cat feet. It sits looking. over harbor and city on silent haunches. and then moves on. Carl Sandburg.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Shakespeare Glossary](https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Glossary.aspx), "new" at this time could be used as an adverb meaning "newly, freshly, recently, just" or "immediately, just." Here it presumably has the first sense: "though altered new" means "though newly altered."

Of course, Shakespeare only has one syllable left in that line if he wants to keep it metrical:

```
 x    /    x     /  x   /    x    /   x    /
May still seem love to me, though altered new:
```

Comment: Good find that is. Let's see how generous folks are around here.